# Plotshape crossover and crossunder are working wrong

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to "plotshape"

1. crossover(MACD,Signal) when both (MACD & Signal) > 0
2. crossunder(MACD,Signal) when both (MACD & Signal) < 0

But the following codes are plotting different from what I expected...
When "Signal" is crossing the 0 line, it plots even though MACD and signal are not crossed. I am not sure what is the problem.. Please anyone can help, I 'll be very appreciated

[image]

```
//@version=4
study(title="MACD", shorttitle="MACD", overlay=false)

// Getting inputs
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", type=input.integer, defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", type=input.integer, defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
signal_length = input(title="Signal Smoothing", type=input.integer, defval = 9)

// Calculating
fast_ma = ema(MACD_src, fast_length)
slow_ma = ema(MACD_src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal =  ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal

// Plot colors
col_grow_above = #26A69A
col_grow_below = #FFCDD2
col_fall_above = #B2DFDB
col_fall_below = #EF5350
col_macd = #0094ff
col_signal = #ff6a00

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
Plot   ////////////////////////
// macd and signal
plot(macd, title="MACD", color=col_macd, transp=0)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal, transp=0)
hline(0)

Above_0 = (macd >= 0) and (signal >= 0)
Below_0 = (macd <= 0) and (signal <= 0)
UP = Above_0 ? crossover(macd, signal)  : na
DN = Below_0 ? crossunder(macd, signal) : na
plotshape(UP, style= shape.xcross, location= location.top, color=color.green)
plotshape(DN, style= shape.xcross, location= location.top, color=color.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move cross functions outside the ternary operator.

```
UP = Above_0 and crossover(macd, signal)
DN = Below_0 and crossunder(macd, signal)
```